# SQL Server: running every sql script in a directory

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm running SQL Server 2008 locally. I have a pile of scripts I would like to run on my local database. I can connect to the server and run them manually but I have over a 100 scripts, and I'm sure there is a way to do this. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: There's got to be a gazillion of those utilities out there!! Search on Google or Bing - you'll find **tons** of hits.... e.g. http://download.cnet.com/SQL-Batch-Executor/3000-10254_4-10385995.html or http://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/Servers/Database-Utils/xSQL-Script-Executor.shtml or **MANY MANY MORE**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate all query files in a directory and execute them with [osql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213087%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) utility.

```
@echo off
for %%f in (*.sql) do (
    echo executing %%f
    osql -E -i %%f
)

pause
```

Comment: As of SQL Server 2005, I would recommend using **`sqlcmd.exe`** instead of `osql` - but other than that - good answer